# Endless Scrolling in Marionette?

Tags: jquery, api, scroll, marionette

I am trying to add an endless scroll into my marionette view for this "Games View"
I am sure my logic is on the right track, but I was told that I may need to modify something directly in jQuery or something dumb like that, as using a "infinite scroll" in a composite view.. their may be some quirks to it.

Here is some code.

```
            getGames: (url, params = {}) ->
        _.defaults params,
            oauth_token: msgBus.reqres.request "get:current:token"
            #country: "us"
        games = new GamesCollection
        games.url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/#{url}?callback=?"
        games.fetch
            reset: if params.offset is 0 then true else false
            data: params
        games

        msgBus.reqres.setHandler "games:top:entities", ->
    API.getGames "games/top",
        limit: 25
        offset: 0
```

---

**Msgbus calls.**

```
msgBus.reqres.setHandler "games:scroll", (page) ->
    API.getGames "games/top",
        limit: 25
        offset: page

        msgBus.reqres.setHandler "games:top:entities", ->
    API.getGames "games/top",
        limit: 25
        offset: 0
```

---

**Games Controller**

```
            gameRegion: (collection)  ->
        view = @getGameView collection
        @listenTo view, "childview:game:item:clicked", (child, args) ->  # listen to events from itemview (we've overridden the eventnamePrefix to childview)
            console.log "game:item:clicked" , args.model
            Backbone.history.navigate "games/streaming/#{args.model.get("game").name}", trigger:false
            msgBus.commands.execute "app:stream:list", @layout.streamRegion, args.model

        @listenTo view, "games:fetchmore", (page) -> 
            #console.log "game:item:clicked" , args.model
            msgBus.reqres.request "games:scroll", page
```

---

**And lastly, the Games View**

```
    define ['apps/games/list/templates', 'views/_base', 'msgbus'], (Templates, AppView, msgBus) ->

class GameItem extends AppView.ItemView
    template: _.template(Templates.gameitem)
    tagName: "li"
    className: "col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
    triggers:
        "click" : "game:item:clicked"

TopGameList: class TopGameList extends AppView.CompositeView
    template: _.template(Templates.topgame)
    itemView: GameItem
    itemViewContainer: "#gameitems"
    events:
        'scroll': 'checkScroll'

    checkScroll: (e) ->
        console.log "scroll", e
        triggerPoint = 100 #100px from the bottom
        if @el.scrollTop + @el.clientHeight + triggerPoint > @el.scrollHeight
            console.log "trigger:scroll"
            @collection.offset += 1 #Load next page
            msgBus.events.trigger "games:fetchmore", @collection.offset
```

---

If you are curious about the API I am using, here is a link to the github...

[Twitch TV API](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API)

> Thanks guys, sorry for the long post. 
>   cheers.

Answer (score 2):

***Didnt read through all the code, but pagination/endless scrolling can be achieved with backbone in the following ways...

```
Backbone Paginator (Most popular): 
https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator 

Backbone Pageable (API was easier IMO)
https://github.com/wyuenho/backbone-pageable
```

I'm not sure how many items you want in your collection, but I would recommend having a     button that allows you to fetch more items so you don't load everything into memory. Fetch like 10 -100 at a time. Or add an event that loads more items when scrolled to the bottom.

I was trying to do the same thing before with Marionette, but eventually settled with Elasticsearch and its built in pagination for the longterm. But in the meantime the above plugins should work.

**Edit: Also whenever you fetch just append the results to the bottom with jquery or js